# PHP Calling method inside method

Tags: php

PHP student here Consider the following 2 methods the 1 method checks if a user exists the other registers a user.

```
public function is_registered($userEmail) 
{
   $this->email = $userEmail;

   $sql = "SELECT * from users WHERE email = :email";

   $stmnt = $db->prepare($sql);
   $stmnt->bindValue(':email', $userEmail);

   $check = $stmnt->execute();

   if($check >= 1) {
      return true;
   }
   else {
      return false;
   }
}


public function register_user($email, $pword, $firstname, $lastname)
{
   $this->email = $email;

   //call method is_registered inside register user class
   $registered = $this->is_registered($email);

   if($registered == true){
      die("USER EXISTS");
   }
   else {
      //continue registration
   }

 }
```

Although this might not be the best use case example I basically want to know:

1. Is "normal / good practice" to call a method inside a method. Another use case might be calling a `get_email()` method inside a `login()` method or similar method where you need an email address.
2. What is the difference if I set a property inside a method or just access the passed parameter directly? Example:

Method with set property

```
public function is_registered($userEmail)
{
   $this->email = userEmail // SET PROPERTY

   $sql = "SELECT * from users WHERE email = :email";
   $stmnt = $db->prepare($sql);
   $stmnt->bindValue(':email', $userEmail);
}
```

Method with no set property.

```
public function is_registered($userEmail) 
{
   //NO SET PROPERTY
   $sql = "SELECT * from users WHERE email = :email";
   $stmnt = $db->prepare($sql);
   $stmnt->bindValue(':email', $userEmail);
}
```

Hope this makes sense, any help or guidance much appreciated.

Comment: @Akintunde007 yeah although not part of question, I use `global $db` to access `$db`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the point of view of `OOP`, both approaches are kinda weird. Since your `User` class doesn't seem to be static, and since the e-mail address is one of the major uniqueness discriminant for authentication, your class should be instantiated with a valorized `email` property that never changes... either upon database extraction (1) or form filling (2):

```
$user = new User(..., $auth->email); (1)
$user = new User(..., $_POST['registration_mail']); (2)
```

On the top of that, a method named `is_registered` should really not mess with assignments. All it should do is to check whether the current `User` instance class is defined in your database or not.

In your first approach, the risk is to mess up everything. Let's suppose you have the following user:

```
$user = new User('John', 'john@domain.com');
```

Now, let's see what happens when, by mistake, you pass the wrong email as argument:

```
$result = $user->is_registered('marley@domain.com');
echo $user->name; // John
echo $user->email // marley@domain.com
```

In your second approach, you should not allow the `is_registered` to accept any argument since, as I explained you before, that property should be defined upon creation to avoid fatal mistakes. Let's bring back the same user we used in the first example:

```
$user = new User('John', 'john@domain.com');
```

Now, let's see what happens when, by mistake, you pass the wrong email as argument (`john@domain.com` is registered, `marley@domain.com` isn't):

```
$result = $user->is_registered('marley@domain.com'); // false
```

So my suggestion is, initialize the property upon the creation of the instance and never mess with it. Alternatively, you could implement a static function into a utility class that, for a given email, performs the desired check. But try to make your `OOP` design as strict as possible.